# Spring Data Repository - No qualifying bean Injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa, autowired

I'm new to Spring framework.
I just started learning following various guides (http://spring.io/guides) and I'm trying to complete the full tutorial about web services (http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/).

I'm quite stuck on the JPA Datasource definition, because I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'init' defined in main.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [bookmarks.AccountRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [bookmarks.AccountRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [bookmarks.AccountRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at main.Application.main(Application.java:41)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [bookmarks.AccountRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 18 more
```

My main Application class is the following

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner init(AccountRepository accountRepository,
            BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository) {
        System.out.println("Bean!");
        return (evt) -> Arrays.asList(
                "jhoeller,dsyer,pwebb,ogierke,rwinch,mfisher,mpollack,jlong".split(","))
                .forEach(
                        a -> {
                            Account account = accountRepository.save(new Account(a,
                                    "password"));
                            bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account,
                                    "http://bookmark.com/1/" + a, "A description"));
                            bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account,
                                    "http://bookmark.com/2/" + a, "A description"));
                        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

And my pom.xml is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>demo.DemoApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I understand that the dependency injection framework doesn't find any implementation of the AccountRepository interface, which looks like

```java
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
    Optional<Account> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

But the framework should provide "a correct implementation" for the JpaRepository. This is the part I'm not understanding.

Any help would be appreciated, in particular with a pointer where to study  in deep this framework.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
Adding @EnableJpaRepositories("bookmarks") to the Application class, solved the bean resolution issue. But now I get
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class bookmarks.Account

My Account entity class is

```java
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class Account {

    @JsonIgnore
    public String password;
    public String username;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="Account") 
    private Set<Bookmark> bookmarks = new HashSet<>();
    @Id @GeneratedValue 
    private Long id;

    public Account(String name, String password) {
        this.username = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    Account() { } // jpa only

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: WHat packages are your repositories in?

Comment: My project structure is the following:
src/main/java
    bookmarks
        Account.java
        AccountRepository.java
    main
        Application.java

so the repositories are in the package bookmarks.

Comment: ID download the source and work it from there - https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-bookmarks/blob/master/rest/src/main/java/bookmarks/Application.java - not much help - but you are working the tutorial

Comment: Thank you, I already explored that repo, without any success :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For JpaRepository to be picked by framework, you need to enable it in your configuration - add

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("your.package.with.jpa.repositories")
```

in your `@Configuration` file.

---

**upd**

here is sample configuration for jpa repositories to work:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    // configure your datasource
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emfb.setDataSource(dataSource);
    emfb.setPackagesToScan("your.package.with.model"); 
    emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    emfb.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap()); 
    return emfb;
}

@Bean 
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}

public Map<String, ?> jpaPropertiesMap() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"); // assumption based on your pom-file
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "..."); // you need to google for appropriate option
    return properties;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I added @EnableJpaRepositories("bookmarks") annotation on the main class "Application", but now I'm getting the following error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class bookmarks.Account.
The account class is a @Entity annotated class

Comment: @besil well, since you are using `JpaRepository`, your `Account` has to  be jpa entity. it should be annotated with `@Entity` and have an id property - annotated with `@Id`.

Comment: Yes, it is. The bean entity resolution seems working now, but I don't understand why the Account class is throwing the error

Comment: @besil do you have jpa provider configured in your project?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know. How can I check? Could you point me to some documentation? Thank you!

Comment: @besil basically, you need an EntityManager configured in your project. here is an example that poped first on google: http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/13/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-3-1-and-jpa/ . You need to complete items 2 and 4

Comment: @besil note that `packagesToScan` refers to package with your model - i.e. `Account`, not repositories.

Comment: Thank you for answering my original question. However, I'm not understanding how to solve the EntityManager configuration issue :(

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I solved without declaring the EntityManager as you did. I'm going to update my question, including the answer to my second issue.

Answer (score 2):

The final (working) configuration for solving the issues is the following (just following the documentation http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/).

The solution was adding

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in the pom.xml, and changing the

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
private Set<Bookmark> bookmarks = new HashSet<>();
```

in the Account class (the error was: mappedBy="Account", capital letter...).

Full code below:

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MyRestService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>demo.MyRestServiceApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Account class

```java
package bookmarks;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class Account {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    private Set<Bookmark> bookmarks = new HashSet<>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    public Set<Bookmark> getBookmarks() {
        return bookmarks;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String password;
    public String username;

    public Account(String name, String password) {
        this.username = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    Account() { // jpa only
    }
}
```

Application class

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(AccountRepository accountRepository,
            BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository) {
        return (evt) -> Arrays.asList(
                "jhoeller,dsyer,pwebb,ogierke,rwinch,mfisher,mpollack,jlong".split(","))
                .forEach(
                        a -> {
                            Account account = accountRepository.save(new Account(a,
                                    "password"));
                            bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account,
                                    "http://bookmark.com/1/" + a, "A description"));
                            bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account,
                                    "http://bookmark.com/2/" + a, "A description"));
                        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```